# Can't get the next Destiny level to show up

Tags: destiny

I am new to the game and finished level 7 (the dark beyond) on the moon.  The next level doesn't show up.  I have gone to the tower and can't figure out how to get to the next moon level.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what active quest(s) you have (press Start, then go one screen to the left)? Do any of them tell you where to go?

Comment: One note, the level numbers aren't numbered orders for missions, those are the levels that enemies in the mission will be at.

Comment: The next mission is "The World's Grave".  The number associated with missions is not the level number it is the recommended level.  The World's Grave is on the left side of the map of the Moon.  Does it appear for you there?

Comment: You can get anywhere in the game by following the un-filled in missions or going to the places where there is a green/purple icon showing.

Comment: Thanks.  All of the other moon missions are greyed out so I can't select them.

Answer (score 1):

The game is designed to always give you an indication of where to go. From using your ghost to show the next white icon when in on a mission to moving around in the tower.

When in the "select destination" screen, the next place to go will have a green or purple icon *centered on the planet*. Sometimes there are several planets marked. Going to one of these planets with the icon will progress your story in that story line.

If the icon is centered on the Tower (note that when it is above that is usually mail or cryptarch) then when you arrive there should be a floating green icon indicating a direction to go. There are three "sub zones" on the Tower, and the entrance to one of these, if that is the direction needed, will contain a green diamond with a white center if you need to travel into that zone in order to progress the story.

Similarly to these, while on a mission if uncertain where to go bringing up the ghost will also bring up a small blurb of text for the current objective in addition to a white icon showing in the direction of where to go to complete the objective *and* the icon's shape will indicate what the objective type is going to be.

- Fetch objectives have triangle shapes inside their white icons.
- Kill objectives have a large diamond surrounded by 4 small diamonds inside their white icons.
- Ghost objectives have the white icons that are similar to the appearance of your Ghost.
- Survey objectives have speedometer shapes inside their white icons.
- Assassination objectives have a star inside a circle inside their white icons.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you are currently using a trial account. Please either insert the disk, buy the digital copy or re-install the digital copy, depending on your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out.  I am still trying to understand how the flow works and I had to go to the Tower and talk to the speaker in order to unlock the next mission.  It really could be a lot clearer, in my opinion.